# Does ConTeXt have a language code for Korean?

Tags: context, languages, cjk, context-mkiv

ConTeXt has various language codes, listed [in this article](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Language_Codes) at the ConTeXt wiki. I do not see Korean listed. I have tried `\language[ko]`, and the document compiles, but I have no way to verify if it is successful, as `\language[anything]` also compiles.

- Does ConTeXt have a language code for Korean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Just copying Taco's response to an answer to get this question out of the list of questions without answer.)

To specify Korean text, use

```
\language[kr]
```

Taco also mentions `[...conversion=kr...]`, but I don't know what that means. Grepping the sources for `conversion=` suggests this key is used with commands like `\setuppagenumbering` and `\setupsubformulas`, but mostly with the value `conversion=romannumerals`. I personally couldn't get `conversion=kr` to work.